# Is a nonlinear compact operator still compact if multiplied by a scalar function

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, nonlinear-analysis

This questions relates to *nonlinear* compact operators. That is an operator $D$ on a Hilbert space $H$ with $D: H\rightarrow H$ with $D$ defined to be compact on $S\subset H$ if $D$ is continuous and if for every bounded set $V \subset S$, $D(S)$ is a relatively compact set. (For the purposes of this question I'm assuming $H$ is real and only considering the case of an operator on a bounded set V rather than the more general case).

Now suppose we also have a nonlinear scalar function $f:H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that $f$ is continuous and that f(V) is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ with $V$ a bounded set in $H$.

Is the operator f(x)Dx (that is the scalar function multipled by the operator) also a compact operator on $V$?

I've come up with a 'proof' (given below). But I can't help feeling I'm missing something here. Any help on whether my proof is actually correct or whether this result is simply a corrollary of  another result or indeed false would be very gratefully received.

*Proof*
Let $Tx:=f(x)Dx$. Then the continuity of $T$ follows immediately. 
Let $v_n$ be an arbitary sequence in $V$. Since $D$ is compact there exists a subsequence $v_{n_i}$ for which $Dv_{n_i}$ converges. Now consider the sequence $f(v_{n_i})$ by Bolzano-Weierstrass this has a convergent subsequence $f(v_{n_{i_j}})$. That is we are now considering a sub-subsequence. The sub-subsequence $Dv_{n_{i_j}}$ must also converge. Hence our operator $Tv_{n_{i_j}} =f(v_{n_{i_j}}) Dv_{n_{i_j}} $ must converge. So T(V) is relatively compact and thus T is a compact operator.

Comment: Your proof is doing the following: $D:H\to H$ maps bounded sets to relatively compact sets and so does $f:H\to \Bbb C$. Hence $\overline{f(V)}\times\overline {D(V)}$ is compact in $\Bbb C\times H$ for $V$ bounded. Since scalar multiplication is jointly continous you have that the product $\overline{f(V)} \cdot \overline{D(V)}$ is compact. But this set contains the image of $V$ under $x\mapsto f(x)D(x)$ hence that image is relatively compact.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. To check I've understood this: define $g:\mathbb{C}\times H \rightarrow H$ with $g:(\lambda,v) \mapsto \lambda v$. Since $g$ is continuous $g({\overline f(V)} \times {\overline D(V)})$ is compact. Let $Tx:= f(x)D(x)$. Then since $T(V) \subset g({\overline f(V)} \times {\overline D(V)})$ it follows that $T(V)$ is relatively compact. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.